# Need clarification on how to declare a method in Java

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors, declaration

My textbook says to "add multiple methods".  But where on earth do I put the method?

I figured I should put it inside main but as soon as I put the `public static void` part, there's an error!! And when I put a method outside of main, there's an error telling me *"missing method body, or declare abstract"*.

What goes inside main and what goes OUT of main?

```
package testin;

public class Testin {
    public static void printAmerican(String day, String month, int date, int year);{
        day="Monday"
        month="March"
        date=14;
        year=2017;                        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
};
```

Comment: Also, if you're asking about errors or exceptions, **always** post the full error/exception message and pertinent code in with your question, and indicate which lines of code are involved. These messages are super important and usually tell you **exactly** what you're doing wrong, leading you to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Do a google search for any simple program and you will see how it works. Also, any time you post a question about your code not working, include the broken code and the error.

Comment: Also, you generally cannot include part of a statement and expect the absence of an error.  That's why only the "public static void" part alone causes an error.

Comment: If you mean that you have an IDE that is telling you there's an error: IDE's will often show errors on constructs that you haven't finished typing.  If I'm starting to type in a method and I pause after `public static void`, it will show an error if I wait longer than about 1 second.  Don't worry about those.  Only worry about errors if you think that a unit of code (like a statement or method) is finished and the IDE still says it's an error.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone for your comments.  I have edited my post by adding the actual code.

Comment: Get rid of the `;` before the `{` on line 10.  Also some of the statements in the method body need semicolons.  Also I don't know what `printAmerican` is supposed to do, but it probably wants to **use** the parameters that you pass to the method, not immediately overwrite them with other values.

Comment: After a bit of editing, this looks like a good question now. Lauren, please write your questions like this: correct casing as much as you can, leave out non-essential chat, and show your problematic code in the first cut. You'll get a lot of helpful eyeballs then. This may close as "typographical error" but you've got a solution `:-)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semicolon in the wrong spot, before the `{`:

```
(String day, String month, int date, int year);{...
 //                                           ^ Here
```

Get rid of that. It doesn't make any sense to have one there.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the problem with that line!!

Comment: @LaurenMcCabe Glad I could help. If this fixed it, hit the accept button to mark the question as resolved

Answer (score 1):

Methods are declared WITHIN the class body.

```
public SomeClass {

    private int someIntVariable = 0;

    public method doSomeThingUseless(int myIntValue) {
        someIntVariable = myIntValue;
       }

}
```

Comment: When I put the method inside class, I get the same errors described above.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say main, not class.  I get error when trying to declare a method within main.